# Android Violation of Personal and Sensitive Information policy

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have developed a react native a year ago detached from expo  but still able to use some api of expo, not sure what exactly was but i remember smth like expo kit.

Thou recently I have received a message from Google Play saying:

> Your app is using the Branch IO SDK, which is uploading users
>   Installed Packages information to https://api.branch.io/v1/applist
>   without a prominent disclosure. Prior to the collection and
>   transmission, it must prominently highlight how the user data will be
>   used, describe the type of data being collected and have the user
>   provide affirmative consent for such use. Make sure to also post a
>   privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Developer
>   Console and from within the Play distributed app itself.

I am not sure where to look for what I am using so I am collecting some user info, does the expo itself added this library sdk, i don't remember adding such thing.

in gradle app: I have noticed I have this under dependencies:

`compile 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.6.1'` not sure if this dependency has to do anything with the violations of personal information since this dependency consists of smth .branch.

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: your app needs privacy policy because you are using that library

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko, can you explain in more details, does that mean I should add something or remove this library, or at least I dont know what is that used for!

Comment: I have removed that line of code .io.branch.sdk at all since i dont need to store any user info dont know how this library came here.